# Graph of the history of databases

Tags: history

There are several nice graphs (in the computer science sense: nodes and arcs) of the history of programming languages, such as http://rigaux.org/language-study/diagram.html

I haven't found one of operating systems in general, but there was one for UNIX around somewhere, and this one for Linux distributions was easy to find: https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-kernel-history-and-distribution-time-line.html

Database systems have a rich and tangled history, for most of which as far as I can tell documentation exists, but is not as easy to find as for more familiar matters such as home computing.

Does there exist a graph or other form of comprehensive overview of the history of database and ERP systems?

Comment: While the topic is interesting, this question asks of a kind of list answer (in graphic form) - eventually  even a link only answer, a fact making it non-fitting to RC.SE, doesn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the german wikipedia article on databases mentions the

**Genealogy of Relational Database Management Systems**

you can find it at

https://hpi.de/naumann/projects/rdbms-genealogy.html

Comment: Well, this is quite a link only anyswer - not your fault, as the question asks for som. Also, the graph is missing out many data base system while focusing rather on Modern (and PC-Alike) developments, this

Comment: @Raffzahn I've only had a brief look at it but it seems reasonably comprehensive to me. What do you think is missing (granted that it focuses on relational databases only)?

Comment: @JeremyP Next to all prior mainframe products. And yes, most important, everythin that didn't sell itself as relational.

Comment: @Raffzahn It advertises itself as a genealogy of *relational* database management systems. You wouldn't expect to see non relational systems in there. And there weren't any significant relational database management systems before IBM invented them.

Comment: [The current version of the linked diagram](https://hpi.de/fileadmin/user_upload/fachgebiete/naumann/projekte/RDBMSGenealogy/RDBMS_Genealogy_V6.pdf) indicates that MS Access was forked from VisualFoxPro and implies no connection between FoxPro and dBase - and no mention of CockroachDB or Google Spanner either, _hmpf_.